# Element with fixed aspect ratio and fixed height without js

Tags: html, css

I need to style one of the containers in my app so that it has fixed aspect ratio and fills an outer container in width or height depending on viewport width. While filling width is as simple as setting

```
#myDiv{
  width:100%;
  padding-bottom: 50%
}
```

It doesn't seem like there is any obvious way to set the height to 100% and then left padding to 200% of that. Is this even possible without playing with bounding boxes in js?

Comment: yeah not possible without js (I think) - I've always found there is a point where you need to switch from width 100% to height:100% - which you can't do without js unless you code a media query for every possible scenario

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you can try viewport height another css proeprty.
By giving like this:

```
#mydiv{
width:100%;
height:100vh;
}
```

vh means viewport height that will cover the container t0 viewport height.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is possible with media queries and "aspect-ratio". MDN says it's not supported by chrome, but it must be outdated, it works.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zWpmYK

```
#a4{
  background: #f00;
  width:100%;
  padding-bottom: 141%;
}
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 21/29) {
  #a4{
    background: #0f0;
    height: 98vh;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    width: 69vh;
  }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/@media/aspect-ratio